# How do I pass a variable to a function in this context? (for an onclickevent)

Tags: javascript

```
function check(child) { 
    var y = "<span onclick=remove(" + child + ") onmouseover='hove(this)'>x</span>";
    child = child + " " + y;
    send = '<span  class="elements" >' + child + '</span>' ;
 }

 function remove(child) {
    // some of mycode;
 }
```

These are the 2 functions I have. `child` is a variable passed from one function to the check() function and again I'm trying to pass this child value to remove function, adding to the onclick event of span tag  but it does not seem to work. I am unable to get out of this.

I want to add onclick event to the span tag and it should pass the child value to remove function.

Comment: I really can't work out what your code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "send". Directly assign to innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = '<span  class="elements" >' + child + '</span>' ;
```

Edited:

I am guessing that your end goal is to have a span tag that looks like this?

```
<span class="elements" >
    ABC <span onclick="remove('ABC')" onmouseover='hove(this)'>x</span>
</span>
```

Then the code may be:

```
function check(child) { 
    var y = "<span onclick=\"remove('" + child + "')\"" onmouseover='hove(this)'>x</span>";
    child = child + " " + y;
    send = '<span  class="elements" >' + child + '</span>' ;
```

}

Comment: that was a mistake actual question is how to pass a variable in onclick event please answer that

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what `child` is, you'll probably want quotes around it:

```
var y = "<span onclick=remove('" + child + "')
```

Also, you can't save the innerHTML of an element to a variable, and then assign over the variable.  All you're doing is writing over the variable, not the actual innerHTML.  So change this:

```
var send = document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML;
send = '<span  class="elements" >' + child + '</span>' ;
```

to

```
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML = 
    '<span  class="elements" >' + child + '</span>';
```